# Unsupported package?

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone !

**Begginer here**

**ROS INDIGO**

I'm trying to install [This package](https://github.com/hasauino/rrt_exploration_tutorials) but I have some trouble :
I'm following the "read me" tutorial (replacing evidently ros-kinetic by ros-indigo) and everything's fine furthermore, i don't have error message when i catkin_make.
Then, i'm trying to source devel/setup.bash then

```
roslaunch rrt_exploration_tutorials single_simulated_house.launch
```

but there is this error message :

```
The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['articulation_tutorials'] [ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
```

i'm trying to find the package with rospack find, but it didn't seem to be registered. neither with rospack list.

is it due to the fact i'm using a new workspace for this tutorials ?

thanks by advance for you help (and sorry for the bad english !)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276615/unsupported-package-?/) by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-11-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-11-24**:
What was the error message? You posted the command that you ran instead of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nevermind i didn't search enough, and i just found the solution sorry !
found the solution on [this topic](https://answers.ros.org/question/143496/roslaunch-is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package-nor-is-a-launch-file-name/)

i didn't source ros correctly

```
$ source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) with karma: 62 on 2017-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0